# Why compare string with generated string fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Can anyone explain why the below isn't the same?

```
const j = 't1'
const t = 1

if (j === ['t'].concat(t)) {
  console.log('the same')
}
```

I would have expected that I am comparing `t1` with `t1`, but I guess I am not?

Comment: `['t'].concat(t)` - array (`["t", 1]`), `j` - string (`t1`). Try `j === ['t'].concat(t).join("")`

Comment: And even with a non-strict `==` comparison it would be `if ( "t1" == "t,1" ) { ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `Array.prototype.concat` method which returns an array.

```
['t'].concat(t);  //["t", 1]
```

This is not equal by value or type to `'t1'`

However, if you had used `String.prototype.concat`, you would get the expected results.

```
't'.concat('1'); //"t1"
```

Comment: to be absolutely precise then `["t", 1]` :)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `['t'].concat(t)` returns an array `['t', 1]` which is not the same as `'t1'`.

Comment: The comparison will already fail on the different types